# cost of finding nxn cramer's method

Tags: calculus

I want to ask about the cost of finding the solution of a $n \times n$ linear equation system by cramer's method, which means the number of operations needed to compute the solution using cramer's method.
for example :

> 1) to find the cost of 2x2 system we need: cost= (3 Determinant-2x2) + (2 divisions)
>                                          but (Determinant-2x2) = 2 multiple + 1 addition=3
>                        //// total cost = 11 operations
>
> 2) to find the cost of 3x3 system we need: cost= (4 Determinant-3x3) + (3 divisions)
>                   but (Determinant-3x3) =(3 Determinant-2x2) + 3 multiple + 2 addition=14
>                           and  (Determinant-2x2) = 2 multiple + 1 addition=3
>                         //// total cost = 59 operations
>
> 3) to find the cost of 4x4 system we need: cost= (5 Determinant-4x4) + (4 divisions)
>              but (Determinant-4x4) =(4 Determinant-3x3) + 4 multiple + 3 additions
>   total coast= 319

So what is the general formula for the computational cost of the solution of a $n\times n$ linear equation system using Cramer's method?

Comment: Hello seraj hasani, welcome to Math.SE. Please note the cost you seek also specifies the determinant algorithm to be a "stupid" implementation of Laplace's formula. For example, any $0 \cdot \ldots$ terms will be evaluated, regardless of the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

**Cost of Cramer's method in $n$ dimensions:**
$$(n+1) C_{\det}(n) + n$$
($C_{\det}(n)$ be the cost of a $n\times n$ determinant, $+n$ for the divisions)

**Cost of $n\times n$ determinant:**
To honor you participation, I give the recusion formula:
$$C_{\det}(1) = 0$$
(*no computations required for that, just return the input*)
$$C_{\det}(n) = (n-1) + n(3+ C_{\det}(n-1)) = n C_{\det}(n-1) + 4n - 1$$

Comment: thank you AlexR I will try myself

Comment: @serajhasani No problem. Notice you will at first get a recusion formula $C_{\det}(n) \sim C_{\det}(n-1)$

Comment: I have a problem to find the recursion formula..........
Please help me....

Comment: @serajhasani The Laplace formula is given by
$$\det A = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij} \det(A_{ij})$$
Where $A_{ij} \in \mathbb{K}^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}$ for $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$

Comment: but I need it in the form of nxn

Comment: You should first get used to the [notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).
You seek the "cost" of above formula.

Comment: I know how to find the determinant but the problem is how to find the cost of any nxn system

Comment: i'm really sorry AlexR if I gig you..
I have a problems in math and I try to be good

Comment: Okay, first a sum of $n$ summands (as in the formula) costs $n-1$ additions. $(-1)^{i+j}$ when implemented correctly costs $1$ multiplication, so we compute
$$n_{\text{summands}} \cdot (1_{(-1)^{i+j}} + 2_{\text{multiplications}} + C_{\det}(n-1))$$
Summands and have $n-1$ additions coming atop of that.
Are you okay by that?

Comment: really I want the formula like cost of finding (A^-1b)= 2n^2 -n
so Iwant the form of finding cost of determinant in n variable so that when I want the cost of determinant of 2x2 give me 3

Comment: Using the recursion term you get
$$C_{\det}(2) = 2\cdot 0 + 8 - 1 = 7$$
(we have $C_{\det}(1) = 0$ as recusion start)
That's because you don't exploit the static nature of "ac-bd" but instead compute
$(-1)^0\cdot a\cdot \det(c) + (-1)^1\cdot b \cdot \det(d)$

Comment: The leibniz formula would work well to evaluate the cost of a determinant